# Laravel 5: Populate checkbox from related model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get this form to populate the checkboxes from the database when showing the form. I have been searching and trying for days, and I can not find an answer.

Each Area has many Tools, connected in a pivot table `area_tool`.

Each "template" has many "areas", connected by a pivot table named `temparea`, with the fields `id`, `area_id` and `template_id`.

Each area in a specific template can have many "tools", connected by a pivot table named `temparea_tool`, with the fields `temparea_id` and `tool_id`.

By using this form (and my controller functions) I have been able to generate a checkbox for all tools connected to a specific area, and to sync those tools in `temparea_tool`.

However, I am very unsure of how I can get the form to populate the checkboxes to show which tools have already been chosen for this specific temparea. What I need is to get to pass `tool_id` from the `temparea_tool` for this specific temparea as the third argument in the form-field.

EDIT: 
After a lot of more hours, I have now somehow managed to generate an array that I can pass to the view, where the array key is the template area and the array value is an array of tool_ids selected for this template area. The array can look like this:

```
array:9 [▼
 15 => array:2 [▼
      0 => 1
      1 => 4
 16 => 4
 45 => array:2 [▶]
 47 => 4
 38 => 5
 48 => 4
 49 => 4
 50 => array:2 [▶]
 51 => 4
]
```

So I need a way to use this array (or some other way) to populate these checkboxes when the form is loaded.

Therefore I figure as the third parameter to the checkbox-field I need to check if $array has a key with value $area->pivot->id and if this key contains value $tool->id. As you can see the array is a multidimensional array. I do not now if this can be done or the syntax for it. Would appreciate help.

THE FORM:

```
{!! Form::model($template, array('route' => array('temptoolupdate', $template->id), 'method' => 'put')) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('tempid', $template->id) !!}
<ul>
  @foreach ($template->area as $area)
  <li>
    {{$area->title}}
  </li> 
  <ul>
    @foreach ($area->tool as $tool)
    <li>
      {{$tool->title}}
      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::checkbox('temparea' . "[" . $area->pivot->id ."]". "[]", $tool->id, $temparea->tool_id) !!}
      </div>
    </li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
  @endforeach
</ul>
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::submit('Register tools') !!}
```

Comment: Where you have `$temparea->tool_id` you should have something like `in_array($tool->id, $selTempAreas) ? true : false`. You need to build `$selTempAreas` of course.

Comment: Thanks,but i have tried this. The problem then is that if the tool exists in the array, it will be checked for all areas. I need a way to search the array for the combination of key (temparea_id) and value (tool_id), and this is a multidimensional array because a temparea could have many tools. See the array above.

Comment: Ok, I have come some way by using this as the third argument for the checkbox: 


`(array_key_exists($area->pivot->id, $array) && ($array[$area->pivot->id] == $tool->id))`

This works as long as an area only has one tool selected. If more than one tool is associated with an area, all the boxes are unchecked.